# SDK design in Android to broadcast events

Tags: android, android-service

I am coding an SDK which broadcasts an action on the happening of an event.

The events are captured in background service.

I have three options here.

1. Globally Broadcast an intent.
2. Locally broadcast an intent.
3. use **setComponent**

**First**
The problem with first approach is that if a mobile phone has two or more apps which have the SDK then it will start behaving abruptly and cause issues.
So option 1 is crossed out.

**Second**
Local Broadcasts have to be registered via the code i.e. using an activity.
The problem with this approach is that if the app is killed or not running, I will not be able to receive the event.

**Third**
I did a small POC with setComponent but I am not able to receive the broadcast event. The Broadcast receiver is registered as a received in the manifest file.

Bottom line, my requirement is that my events will be generated from a background service and I should be able to receive those events in the app irrespective of the app running or paused.

Comment: "The problem with this approach is that if the app is killed or not running, I will not be able to receive the event" -- if the app is killed or not running, your service will be killed or not running, and so there is no event.

Comment: @CommonsWare, You can have your service running if you kill your app or the app is not running.

Comment: Since a service is part of an app, if the app containing the service is not running, the service is not running. It is possible for a service to be running when there are no *activities* running, but activities != app.

Answer (score 2):

You have the **4th** and might be **best alternative**: use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

[image]
To send message (which can be any POJO class instance)

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new SomePojoClass("Hello EventBus!”);
```

To receive message:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

// This method will be called when a SomePojoClass instance is is posted
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(SomePojoClass event){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Just that simple!

Comment: Is the Event Bus available for Android version on or before API 11 i.e. less than Android 2.3?

Comment: @VaibhavRanglani,  I did not see any constraint regarding the API levels. Double check it via the links or google it yourself.

Comment: EventBus does not seem to be a class from Android SDK. Can you please point out the library it is a part of. Thanks!

Comment: @VaibhavRanglani AFAIR eventbus does not use anything Android specific. It is a pure Java implementation.